# AR app does not work shows error "Failed to create AR session"

Tags: android, android-studio, augmented-reality, sceneform

This is my main code

```
package com.example.ar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.ar.core.Anchor;
import com.google.ar.core.HitResult;
import com.google.ar.core.Plane;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.AnchorNode;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ModelRenderable;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.TransformableNode;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final double MIN_OPENGL_VERSION = 3.0;
    ArFragment arFragment;
    ModelRenderable lampPostRenderable;
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({"AndroidApiChecker", "FutureReturnValueIgnored"})

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (!checkIsSupportedDeviceOrFinish(this))
        {
            return;
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ux_fragment);
        ModelRenderable.builder().setSource(this, Uri.parse("lamppost.sfb")).build()
                .thenAccept(renderable -> lampPostRenderable = renderable)
                .exceptionally(throwable ->
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load andy renderable",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                    return null;
                }
                );
        arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener((HitResult hitresult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionevent) -> {
            if (lampPostRenderable == null){
                return;  }
            Anchor anchor = hitresult.createAnchor();
            AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
            anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
            TransformableNode lamp = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
            lamp.setParent(anchorNode);
            lamp.setRenderable(lampPostRenderable);
            lamp.select();
        });
    }

    public static boolean checkIsSupportedDeviceOrFinish(final Activity activity)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Sceneform requires Android N or later");
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Sceneform requires Android N or later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            activity.finish();
            return false;
        }
    String openGlVersionString =
            ((ActivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
                    .getDeviceConfigurationInfo().getGlEsVersion();
    if (Double.parseDouble(openGlVersionString) < MIN_OPENGL_VERSION)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Sceneform requires OpenGL ES 3.0 later");
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Sceneform requires OpenGL ES 3.0 or later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        activity.finish();
        return false;
    }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And I've  also included

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.ar.core"
        android:value="required" />
```

in the Android manifest file.

Gradle module:app has

```
 implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.15.0'
```

and gradle project has

```
 classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.5.0'
```

in dependencies.

My sampledata folder has an obj and a mtl file with the name lamppost.

On opening the app the error is displayed as "Failed to create AR session"
with a black screen and an animation of a hand holding a device rotating in circles [here's how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X7J7.jpg).

Comment: check this
https://gptshubham595.medium.com/unveiling-the-world-of-ar-with-arcore-my-journey-of-exploration-practical-guide-86ac7f54b34

Answer (score 3):

In my case I forgot to include the following code in manifest file

```
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.ar.core"
            android:value="required" />
```

Here's my complete manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar"
        android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.ar.core"
            android:value="required" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Hope it helps! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of the manifest file that is wrote for my ar app.
you forget to put uses permission android.hardware.camera.ar that's why you get this error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.arguide">
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity android:name=".Activities.AddEquipementActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.ArActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.AdminMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.InterventionDetailsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.AddGroupActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.RegisterPasswordActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.RegisterVerifEmailActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.Register2Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.RegisterActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.SplashScreenActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.ar.core"
        android:value="required" />
  </application>
 <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: It works, but I'm unable to see the  object I am using in my sample data.  The camera is opening but I am continuously seeing the  animation of the hand with the device.

Comment: Now all i see is white dots on surfaces

Comment: white dots mean your ar app ddetected a surface just click to load you ar model when you see dots

Comment: please vot to my answer to enable commenting

Comment: I keep tapping the dots but nothing appears to happen

Comment: this poses vulnerability android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"